# Build where clause body

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, collections

I'm trying to find a way to build a where clause and pass it to repository Get() method. It is supposed to filter items which name starts with a specific letter. I was able to construct part of this Where Clause Body, but can't find a way how to handle the scenario where the item name does not start with letter. For example: `_ItemName` or `97_SomeName`.

So, here is my method:

```
protected override Expression<Func<DataSetSettings, bool>> GetWhereClause()
{
    //The user has selected FilterLetter, for example: "A"
    // return all items which name starts with "A"
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterLetter) && !FilterLetter.Equals("All"))
        return (x => x.Name.StartsWith(FilterLetter) && x.Type == Type);

    if (FilterLetter.Equals("Other"))
    {
        //Here i need to extract all items which name does not start with letter
    }

    //return All items of the current type
    return x => x.Type == Type;
}
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework, or is this for memory collections?

Comment: I`m using Entity Framework.

Comment: Did you try something first and get an error? I don't think Entity has a `StartsWith` equivalent.

Comment: I looked around for a bit and was not able to find anything helpful with regard to complex pattern matching in EF. I posted a suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand what you need, I looked around and was not able to find a graceful solution to this. Seems complex string pattern matching is a weak point in EF.

The only way I can see to do this is to either compare against every letter, ie:

```
!x.Name.StartsWith("A") && !x.Name.StartsWith("B") && //on and on to Z
```

Or to make sure the entire list is loaded into memory and then use regular expressions to filter:

```
protected override Expression<Func<DataSetSettings, bool>> GetWhereClause()
{
    var noletter = new Regex("^[^a-z].*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    return (
        x => x.Type == Type && (
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterLetter) || 
            FilterLetter == "All" || 
            (FilterType == "Other" && noletter.IsMatch(x.Name)) ||
            x.Name.StartsWith(FilterType)
        )
    );
}
```

If you do end up going with option of loading everything into memory, you can at least filter based on the `x.Type` first. That seems to be the common denominator in the filtering. At least that way you don't have to load the entire table into memory.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already have a work around with in-memory collection filtering. I was hoping to find a way to do this at database level.

Comment: @vortex SQL Server support regular expressions, but Entity Framework and Linq to SQL do not have translations for them. The best you can do is simulate the `LIKE` operator, which is what `Contains` and `StartsWith` use under the hood.

Comment: for now i`ll use your solution with regex match. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do equals false on your StartsWith

Like this:

`return (x => x.Name.StartsWith(FilterLetter) == false && x.Type == Type);`

Comment: It will not work. If the user selects "Other" for filtering, then i need to bring all items which name does not start with letter. Example: `_Asd, 12Name, *1OtherName`

Comment: @vortex you are saying "letter" but your examples are strings. Is it a single character or multiple characters that can not be at the start of the value?

Comment: @vortex Nevermind. I get it now. You mean non-alphabet characters. So not A - Z, but numbers and characters.

Comment: @jwatts1980, it's alphabetical filter with strings: A, B, C....., Other, All. If the user clicks "A" i filter the items and show just the ones which name starts with A. if he clicks "Other", i need to show the items which i mentioned in my previous comment - `_Asd, 12Name, *1OtherName`

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be make 1 db call of all types into a list, then use linq to query that list. Your example would be making two db calls.

```
List<Type> allTypes = new List<Type>();
List<Type> typesWithA = new List<Type>();
List<Type> typesWOA = new List<Type>();

// make one db call
allTypes = entities.Types.ToList();

typesWithA = allTypes.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(FilterLetter)).ToList();
typesWOA = allTypes.Where(x => !x.Name.StartsWith(FilterLetter)).ToList();
```

Comment: This could be a significant performance hit if `Types` is a large table.

Comment: True. He'd have to figure out another filter of some kind so he wouldn't pull tons of rows.